# Entity Framework: Find on Where

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have to first do a filtering of data, which I do with where, and afterwards find a specific match among these and return it.

I know you can do a Where().First(). But this somehow ignores the fact, that I actually only have unique values among the returned valued from my Where() clause. Therefore I would like to use Find(), just to make it very clear, that there will only be one result and that you do not hide any results behind the First() call.

**Questions**

1. Why can't you do a Where().Find()?
2. What could be a good workaround?

**NOTE** The values are first unique after the Where() call has done its filtering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Single/SingleAsync or SingleOrDefault/SingleOrDefaultAsync.
For example, you can write query :

```
context.Items.Single(e => e.id == id)
```

and it will return single item and exception if there is no items or more than one item for which condition is true.

You can also use SingleOrDefault which will return null if no items are found, but it will still return exception when more than one item is found.

You can find an example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/

Comment: Sorry, Had to be a bit more clear. The data rows are first unique after the filtering has been done with the Where() call.

Comment: @7heViking the point here is that `.Single(predicate)` is the same as `.Where(predicate).Single()`. The `.Where()` call does not filter, it only builds a query. Your query only gets executed once you start enumerating the results. `.Single()` does that, and can take care of the filtering in one call as well.